# Get nothing when scraping Facebook using Casperjs

Tags: javascript, facebook, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to use casperjs to scrape the main page of Facebook. I just modified the example code to scrape Google by casperjs: identify the element with class=fbxWelcomeBoxName, and retrieve the link out of it.

Their example works fine for Google.com, but it seems it does not work when scraping on Facebook. I heard about Facebook banning scraping about customer audience. But my scraping has nothing to do with that. Did I miss anything? Thanks in advance!

```
var links = [];
var casper = require('casper').create();

function getLinks() {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('.fbxWelcomeBoxName');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(e) {
        return e.getAttribute("href");
    });
}

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1');

casper.start('https://www.facebook.com', function() {
    // search for 'casperjs' from facebook form
    this.fill('form#login_form', {
        email: '***your email***',
        pass: '***your password***'
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function() {
    // aggregate results
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});


casper.run(function() {
    // echo results in some pretty fashion
    this.echo(links.length + ' links found:');
    this.echo(' - ' + links.join('\n - ')).exit();
});
```

Result:

```
john@john-ubuntu-ssd:~/tests/casperjs$ casperjs --verbose --log-level=debug --ssl-protocol=any test11.js 
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.facebook.com/, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.facebook.com/, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.facebook.com/"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3 https://www.facebook.com/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form#login_form'
[debug] [remote] Set "email" field value to myemail@hotmail.com
[debug] [remote] Set "pass" field value to ********
[info] [remote] submitting form to https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1, HTTP POST
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 2/3: done in 447ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.facebook.com/, type=FormSubmitted, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://www.facebook.com/"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3 https://www.facebook.com/ (HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 3/3: done in 2265ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 2284ms
0 links found:
 -
```

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS has a default viewportSize of 400x300. So you should set it before you `start` to something desktop-like:

```
casper.viewportSize = {width: 1920, height: 1080};
```

If this doesn't help, you should wait for the `'.fbxWelcomeBoxName'` to appear in the page before scraping it:

```
casper.waitForSelector('.fbxWelcomeBoxName', function(){
    links = this.evaluate(getLinks);
});
```

By the way, there is no reason to have `getLinks`. You should use `casper.getElementsAttribute`:

```
links = casper.getElementsAttribute('.fbxWelcomeBoxName', 'href');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried all your three comments. But it seems the element can not be retrieved. [error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 10000ms expired, exiting. Wait timeout of 10000ms expired, exiting. Does Facebook ban scraping by phantomjs? Like block the request if it detects the browser info in HTTP request as 'phantomjs'.